# Intelligently identifying different accounts as the same user

Tags: php, android, ios, authentication, paypal

The example scenario, to provide context here, is an app (iPhone, Android) that pays the user (using Paypal) to do certain tasks. It currently operates under the assumption every user behaves and has a single account.

**UPDATE** - To clarify how these tasks work. Each user can do a task once, but tasks can be performed by multiple users. This is why I need to make sure a user really is only doing a task one time.

**Example Task**

> Your testing product will arrive in the mail shortly. Please use it for a week and then supply your feedback. Upon completion of your feedback, we will give you $2.50.

---

The issue comes up when a user makes multiple accounts, and then attempts to pay out on these multiple accounts to earn a lot of money quickly. So as a result, you can see this app needs some way to detect that a user is taking advantage it.

Right now our tools for identification are as follows:

**Weak Identifiers** - Things that are subject to change, and are easily faked.

- First Name
- Last Name
- IP Address
- Email

**Strong Identifiers** - Things that are more difficult to change or fake, but still possible to do so.

- IMEI (Android only)
- Paypal Account (only good after first payout, user could mass payout before it mattered)
- Advertiser Id
- Unique Device Id
- Push Notification Token (for app notifications)

Based on these identifiers, and being completely ignorant of the processes used to link accounts together with them I am curious if anyone has advice for doing this type of matching. Also knowing that many of these things can be forged by a devoted person.

For emails, there are ways to fuzzy match but they are quite slow. I have ways of getting some of this done already but I want a best practices and experiences from others before I move further down this rabbit hole.

I am aware there is no 100% surefire way to detect duplicates, but all I want to do is flag the possible duplicates for review and give an administrator the power to review the accounts and either merge or disable them.

**UPDATE - Paypal**
Paypal is a good source, but it only works in very specific cases. To check for a verified account and get the account id back you must have the exact same first and last name on the account provided by the user. This is not always the case. Jonathan could be Jon, Christopher could be Chris, etc. Also, multiple emails can be tied to the same account. So a couple could be sharing and it makes little sense to force them to enter in someone else's name in order to submit their payment.

As for the payout return, this can be avoided by paying out all at once on many accounts. Thus there is nothing to detect until after the payment has already been made. I am not aware of a good way to cancel payments via Paypal so if there is a suggestion there I am all ears.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. If a user earns money on several accounts, then they have done X amounts of Y value. Presumably they would just get paid X * Y if they used a single account. What would be the advantage of using several accounts?

Comment: @halfer In this case, I do not want to pay the user for doing the same task multiple times. Effectively they could do it once but pay out for it on each account. **Edit** - Also, this app has a vested interest in users only doing a task once. I will update the main post with that information.

Comment: Ah, do you want the same task to be carried out by multiple users? If not, the obvious solution would be to remove a task from the available list once someone has done it.

Comment: @halfer, yes I want multiple users to complete the same task but each user can only do the task once.

Comment: If you only offer Paypal as a payment method, then that would probably work: I believe they do their own duplicate filtering e.g. by registering a bank account or payment card.

Comment: @halfer - there's a problem two fold with this. First, you can only verify an account if you have the first and last name of the person _exactly_ as it appears on their paypal account. Second you can have multiple email addresses on the same account legitimately. A husband and wife could have the same paypal account.

Comment: Don't Paypal accounts have unique identifiers that Paypal returns to you once you have made the first payment to them? (I don't know the answer to that, genuine question). You could catch a duplicate there.

Comment: @halfer In regards to your first comment: `Your testing product will arrive in the mail shortly. Please use it for a week and then supply your feedback. Upon completion of your feedback, we will give you $2.50.` In this scenario it is extremely important to deter abuse.

Comment: @Emn1ty bank accounts/credit cards (which translate to paypal accounts in this case) are probably your best bet at limiting multi-accounting. You will not cover 100% of the cases but its better than anything else. The second best are phone numbers. Other than that its a endless race between you and people who spoof device identifiers or reverse engineer your network protocol and bypass the app entirely.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: that doesn't sound like the OP's scenario. However if you were to expand on that in an answer, it may be helpful for someone else.

Comment: @halfer It wasn't meant to imply that this is OP's scenario but it just highlights a scenario which *could* be like OP's. Unfortunately my comment is not worthy to be an answer because it provides no proposed solution :-/

Comment: MonkeyZeus - That is a good example of a scenario where this is important. That would be a likely task to be asked of a user. 

@Vatev - That makes a lot of sense, and I feel the best I can do is wait on an inquiry to Paypal about removing the name the restriction for checking verified accounts. Unfortunately it is "reserved for only the most trusted users". The next best is to ask them to enter the first and last name on the paypal account before their first payout.

Comment: @Emn1ty Maybe it would be a good experience to try your scenario against other websites such as https://www.ipoll.com/ and see what they might have implemented which you have not thought of.

Comment: IMHO, because you're really looking for an _identity solution_ (first) perhaps using [PayPal Identity (Login with Paypal)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/) is a more appropriate API (instead of a "payment solution trying to be an identity solution")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up on this and mention that while I didn't get a solution for this particular item I did get an answer.

> Bank accounts/credit cards (which translate to paypal accounts in this case) are probably your best bet at limiting multi-accounting. You will not cover 100% of the cases but its better than anything else. The second best are phone numbers. Other than that its a endless race between you and people who spoof device identifiers or reverse engineer your network protocol and bypass the app entirely. - @Vatev

Just to resolve this question, the reality is no matter how hard you try to fingerprint a device there are ways to get around it. The only reliable way is to have a lower level access to the phones, a level of access that Google and Apple do not provide and the only alternatives will get your app rejected for misuse of the service.